# Sum columns from database using checkbox

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox, mysqli

I am new to php. I have inserted only a single value in two columns of database. I am trying to add them both using checkbox. 
For example. There is a column with name "englishprice" with only one value 20, and another column "mathprice" with only value 10. I want to sum them using checkbox, Like if I only check englishprice then it shows its price, if I check both then it sums both.

Comment: Can you put some code here? What have you done/tried?

Comment: A checkbox is a UI element in the browser, and has nothing to do with PHP or MySQL. Are you wanting to display the price after a form is submitted in the page returned by some PHP code?

Comment: Cool story bro. Was there a *question*?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   MySQL hasn't a clue what a "checkbox" is, no matter how many values you store in whatever columns.  And PHP doesn't care much about a checkbox either. A checkbox is an HTML element. Typically, if you want behavior associated with the action of clicking a checkbox, that's a "click" event, you can handle the event and call a javascript function. This is left as a comment, not an answer, because I'm not seeing a *question* to answer.

Comment: Yes i want to display the price after submit button is pressed. 
I dont know how to do it.

Comment: Question is how can i do it? How can i make the form and get values in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this >>

Html Code:
 
You need to create two checkbox with value as their prices. Here is sample

```html
<form method="post">
   <input type="checkbox" value="20" name="englishprice"/>englishprice
   <input type="checkbox" value="10" name="mathprice"/>mathprice
   <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $englishprice = isset($_POST['englishprice']) && !empty($_POST['englishprice']) ? (int) $_POST['englishprice'] : 0;
    $mathprice = isset($_POST['mathprice']) && !empty($_POST['mathprice']) ? (int) $_POST['mathprice'] : 0;
    echo "Price " . ($englishprice + $mathprice);
}
?>
```

Comment: I think this will help let me try.